# Angular formly - make custom template for contact filed with country code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I am using Angular formly to create form. I want to create contact field with similar way as showing in below link using **Angular formly**.

[contact filed with country code demo link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes/?)

I have create custom template using angular formly. But I am facing below issues.

1) I am not getting the inserted value within model (key)

2)Value within model sholuld be in below format (+CountryPhonecode) number

ex: +91 9988776655

3)How to apply custom validation.

http://jsbin.com/takutudobe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually , I think you can even create that "flag-code" input by using directives in angular rather than using angular-formly  .

Comment: No katmanco, I want to achieve this only using Angular formly. Because my other form filed are created by angular formly and i want to reused that filed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a **custom template** to wrap that kind of directive:

After a quick Google search I got:

- https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number

More info regarding custom templates:

- http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/custom-templates
- http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates

Examples of 3rd party directives in angular-formly:

- http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/colorpicker
- http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-select
- http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-timepicker
- http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-datepicker
- http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-grid
- [and many more](http://angular-formly.com/#/)

## Update

Model is correctly updated **when validation is passed**:

[image: example]

See updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/nuzize/edit?html,js,console,output

Regarding country code being concatenated to the model, I couldn't find it in the directive's documentation([See mareczek/international-phone-number's Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DYyfGj?p=preview))

```
<p>Model: {{phone}}</p>
<p>Formated view: {{phoneOnlyForm.phone.$viewValue}}</p>
```

Comment: @benoror- Thanks for the reply. I have create custom template using first [link](https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number) . Its working fine but i'm not able get model value.

Comment: Please add a proper jsbin example to ease getting help: help.angular-formly.com

Comment: @benoror- I have added my on code jsbin [link](http://jsbin.com/kasinuzoxa/edit?html,output)

Comment: @Abhijeet fixed, please note the comments, some issues are related to the directive itself, not angular-formly. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct :).

Comment: Thanks benoror !!! I'm trying to show custom error message using validators but its not working.Is it possible to show custom error message?

Comment: Yes! Use ngMessages. There's an example in angular-formly website

Comment: I am trying but not found any good solution :( can you please update in jsbin